# ajax chat skip login

Tags: ajax, chat

I have a site called chat.nhk.io I want to skip the Login page. Or just make it a big button. No Username or password. But I can't find what file I need to edit. My question is where is the login page for Ajax Chat.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

/chat/lib/template/loggedout.html

GLHF